# Is it possible to merge the emailserver and email-server tags?

Tags: support, status-completed

Subject says it all. Can we merge them to "emailserver" ?

Comment: Yep, a Mod will be along to take care of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. I'm not sure if they were the right way around (personally I prefer hyphenated tags), but the non-hypen version had more tags.

Comment: I agree on preferring with hyphen